# Can't connect to GPU when building PyTorch projects

Tags: pytorch, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

Before this, I was able to connect to the GPU through CUDA runtime version `10.2`. But then I ran into an error when setting up one of my projects.

```
Using torch 1.10.1+cu102 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080)
UserWarning: 
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 with CUDA capability sm_86 is not compatible with the current PyTorch installation.
The current PyTorch install supports CUDA capabilities sm_37 sm_50 sm_60 sm_70.
```

After some readings, it seems that `sm_86` is only available for CUDA version `11.0` and above. That's the reason why I upgraded to the latest CUDA version and can't connect to the GPU after this.
I have tried many ways, reinstalling cuda toolkit, PyTorch, torchvision and stuff but nothing works.

CUDA Toolkit I've used:

```
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.6.0/local_installers/cuda_11.6.0_510.39.01_linux.run
$ sudo sh cuda_11.6.0_510.39.01_linux.run
```

PyTorch I've installed (tried both conda and pip):

```
$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch

$ pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu113 torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 torchaudio==0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

These are some basic info:

```
(base) ubuntu@DESKTOP:~$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.10.1+cu113'
>>> x = torch.rand(6,6)
>>> print(x)
tensor([[0.0228, 0.3868, 0.9742, 0.2234, 0.5682, 0.7747],
        [0.2643, 0.3911, 0.3464, 0.5072, 0.4041, 0.4268],
        [0.2247, 0.0936, 0.4250, 0.1128, 0.0261, 0.5199],
        [0.0224, 0.7463, 0.1391, 0.8092, 0.3742, 0.2054],
        [0.3951, 0.4205, 0.6270, 0.4561, 0.4784, 0.5958],
        [0.8430, 0.5078, 0.7759, 0.5266, 0.4925, 0.7557]])
>>> torch.cuda.get_arch_list()
[]
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> torch.version.cuda
'11.3'
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
0
```

Below are my configurations.

```
(base) ubuntu@DESKTOP:~$ ls -l /usr/local/ | grep cuda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jan 24 13:47 cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-11.3/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Jan 17 10:52 cuda-11 -> /etc/alternatives/cuda-11
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Jan 24 13:48 cuda-11.3
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Jan 24 10:17 cuda-11.6
```

ubuntu version:

```
(base) ubuntu@DESKTOP:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

`nvidia-smi`:

```
(base) ubuntu@DESKTOP:~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jan 24 17:22:42 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.39.01    Driver Version: 511.23       CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   26C    P8     5W / 320W |    106MiB / 10240MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4009      G   /Xorg                           N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4025      G   /xfce4-session                  N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4092      G   /xfwm4                          N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     25903      G   /msedge                         N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvcc --version`:

```
(base) ubuntu@DESKTOP:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:15:46_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

PyTorch pip wheels and Conda binaries ship with the CUDA runtime.
But CUDA does not normally come with NVCC, and requires to install separately from `conda-forge/cudatoolkit-dev`, which is very troublesome during the installation.

So, what I did was that I install NVCC from Nvidia CUDA toolkit.

```
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.6.0/local_installers/cuda_11.6.0_510.39.01_linux.run
```

And Conda Pytorch-GPU version

```
$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

As it turns out both installations are not compatible with each other.

Therefore, the step I did to solve this issue:

1. remove any Conda environments in Ubuntu.
2. clean the pip list and Conda list until none of any PyTorch, torchvision,  Cuda etc works.
3. Install Nvidia CUDA toolkit `cuda_11.3` first from Nvidia's official website.
4. Reinstall PyTorch only. `$ pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html`